# Parsing a complex String in java

Tags: java

Here is the String
`(submit: (pdu: 56 4 0 150) (addr: 5 0 us)  (addr: 1 1 88019448888)  (sm: msg: HiTesTgggg)  (opt: ) )`
And I want to parse it like bellow format

```
String addrFirst = "us"
String addrSecond = "88019448888"
String message = "HiTesTgggg"
```

Comment: I have trying by using  msg=inputstring.split('':") but it does not give me  the desired format, I am beginner in java.

Answer (score 3):

Try a regular expression, something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "(submit: (pdu: 56 4 0 150) (addr: 5 0 us)  (addr: 1 1 88019448888)  (sm: msg: HiTesTgggg)  (opt: ) )";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(submit: \\(pdu: [^)]*\\) \\(addr: [^ ]* [^ ]* ([^)]*)\\)  \\(addr: [^ ]* [^ ]* ([^)]*)\\)  \\(sm: msg: ([^)]*)\\)  \\(opt: \\) \\)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}


\\( -> escaped left-bracket
\\) -> escaped right-bracket
[^)]* -> an undefined amount of any character but ")"
[^ ]* -> an undefined amount of any characters but " " (a blank)
([^)]*) -> an undefined amount of any character but ")" -> the () around means it is a matching group
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right path. `split` accepts a regular expression, and regular expressions can be as complex as you can make them. I would recommend you to read a few tutorials on the subject.

You can find an easy and good one [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)